# ¿Como se soluciona el problema con este vector?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Tengo un problema con un vector que se supone que recolecta "n" numero de valores:

```
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de números a comprobar: ");
        n=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());
        valor= new int[n];
         for(int con=1;con<=n;con++){
           System.out.print("Ingrese el ("+con+") numero: ");
           valor[con]=Integer.parseInt(L.nextLine());               
        }
```

pero el código me esta sacando un error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3   at Principal.main(Principal.java:12)")

que se supone afecta a esta parte:

```
        for(int Va=0;Va<n;Va++){
          int s=0;
          if(valor[s]>=valor[Va]){
             nMayor=valor[s];
          }else{s=Va;}
        for(int Va=0;Va<n;Va++){
          int s=0;
          if(valor[s]<=valor[Va]){
             nMenor=valor[s];
        }else{s=Va;}
        }

        System.out.print("El numero mayor es: "+nMayor+" \n El numero menor es: "+nMenor);
        }
```

No se que es lo que esta mal con el código, alguna idea?

Comment: El primer valor lo guardas en valor[1] y cuando lo consultas en el bucle, empiezas en valor[0] y esa posición no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Los arreglos empiezan en 0, y tu `for` empieza en 1, entonces reemplaza esta linea:

```
for(int con=1;con<=n;con++){
```

Con esta:

```
for(int con=0;con<n;con++){
```

Nota como ahora la variable `con` empieza en 0 y termina cuando sea menor a n, por ejemplo si capturas 3 valores así es como se vería tu arreglo:

```
arreglo[0] = valor 1
arreglo[1] = valor 2
arreglo[2] = valor 3
```

Es por eso que te marca un error en la posicion 3 por que esa no existe, existe hasta la posicion 2 ya que empezamos a contar desde 0

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que el conteo de las posiciones de un vector inician desde cero y termina en n-1, donde n es el número de elementos del vector; por ejemplo si declararas el vector:

```
int vector[] = new int[5];
```

Y asignaras de forma manual el valor de cada elemento del vector, tendrías:

```
vector[0] = 2;
vector[1] = 3;
vector[2] = 4;
vector[3] = 5;
vector[4] = 6;
```

Nota como el primer elemento asignado tiene la posición 0 y el último elemento tiene la posición n-1=5-1=4.

Al hacer la comparación de la variable 'con' en el ciclo for, estas excediendo el tamaño del vector que definiste, por eso el compilador te marca error. Lo que que tienes que hacer es corregir esas comparaciones de la siguiente forma:

```
for(int con=0;con<n;con++){
    //resto del código
}
```